# (Python) Как создать переменную с именем из случайных символов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем тепла! Помогите разобраться неопытному новичку!!!
Есть вот такая "программа"...

```
p = int (input ('Введите целое, четное число: '))

player_list = [random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(p)]
class_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
tmp_var_class = random.choices(class_list)
```

1. Из списка player_list я получаю рандомную букву;
2. Из списка temp_class_list рандомную цифру;

Как мне их конкатенировать и инициализировать из полученных данных переменную (только давайте без print, мне нужна вот прям переменная как объект О_о)) ), а затем сделать ее наследником класса?
И
как сделать так, что бы если пользователь водит большое число, буквы в player_list не повторялись, а к ним конкатенировались например другие буквы в lowercase?

В словарь все это дело закинуть не получится т.к. не хэшируемые данные Питон не дает засунуть в словарь... Я так понимаю что для конкатенации "for" мне в помощь, но что-то я не пойму как потом инициализировать переменную...

Составил все как Вы написали:

```
for _ in range(p):

    player_list = random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, p)
    class_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    tmp_var_class = random.choice(class_list)

    var_name = ''.join(player_list).capitalize()

    globals()[var_name] = tmp_var_class
print ([var_name])
```

вывод print = ['Xznqyd']

Я 100% что-то очень очевидное проморгал(

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "инициализировать переменную"? Создать новую переменную и присвоить ей значение? Или что-то другое? Наследником какого именно класса вы её хотите сделать? И что в данном случае вы вообще понимаете под "наследником"? Возможно, вы имели в виду всё-таки не "наследник", а "экземпляр" класса?

Comment: Мне нужно создать переменную. Ну вот как например x = 3...
Только не руками ее создавать, если есть возможность создать переменную через цикл, а для имени переменной использовать рандомный элемент из списка player_list было бы то что нужно)

Извиняюсь что ввожу в заблуждение, терминологию обязательно подтяну...

Comment: Возможно, вы имели в виду всё-таки не "наследник", а "экземпляр" класса? - точно! Именно это и имел в виду.

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar, print в цикле пишите. и скобки квадратные уберите.

Comment: Оно живое!!!! Спасибо всем большущее! Побежал матчасть учить )))))

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, зачем оно вам надо?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кажется, я понял, что вы имеете в виду.

Чтобы создать переменную со случайно сгенерированным именем, можно использовать `globals()` или `locals()`. Это специальные функции, которые дадут вам специальный словарь со всеми переменными в глобальной или локальной области видимости:

```
import random, string


p = int (input ('Введите целое, четное число: '))

player_list = random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, p)
class_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
tmp_var_class = random.choice(class_list)

var_name = ''.join(player_list).capitalize()

globals()[var_name] = tmp_var_class
```

Но на самом деле, почти всегда генерировать имя переменной на ходу - не очень хорошая идея. Лучше создать один словарь и складывать значения в него.

Судя по тому, что вы пишите в вопросе, вы пробовали это сделать, но `player_list` - список, и использовать его в качестве ключа словаря нельзя.

Чтобы из списка символов получить строку, нужно использовать строковой метод `.join` - посмотрите, как в коде выше я создал с помощью него переменную `var_name`. В этой переменной уже полноценная строка, сконкатенированная из списка символов, и её можно использовать в качестве ключа словаря.

UPD: Чтобы создать несколько переменных, делайте так:

```
import random, string

p = int (input ('Введите целое, четное число: '))

for _ in range(p):

    player_list = random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, p)
    class_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    tmp_var_class = random.choice(class_list)

    var_name = ''.join(player_list).capitalize()

    globals()[var_name] = tmp_var_class
    # Но лучше вместо globals() использовать просто словарь
```

Comment: Выдает исключение...
Traceback
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar, я отредактировал мой ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: Я так понимаю, обращаться к этой переменной можно только так `globals()[''.join(player_list).capitalize() + str(tmp_var_class)] = '...'`?

Comment: Все так! Огромное человеческое спасибо)) Вы мне очень помогли! Где тут лайки ставить? )))
Но у меня еще есть маленький вопрос...
В переменную "р" мы получаем число, например 6, как сделать так что бы создать 6 вот таких переменных с динамическими именами?

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar - можно создать цикл `for _ in range(p):` и внутри него поместить весь этот код с созданием переменной. Сейчас допишу в ответ.

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar, дописал. Чтобы оценить ответ, который вам помог, вы можете нажать на галочку и стрелочку вверх слева от ответа, где цифра. Галочкой можно отметить только один ответ для каждого вопроса, а стрелочкой вверх вы можете отмечать сколько угодно ответов (в том числе и к вопросам, которые задали другие люди).

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0, ко всем значениям, которые сложены в globals() можно обратиться как к просто переменной. Но если её имя генерится автоматически уже в процессе выполнения скрипта - то да, заранее его знать не получится, и нужно писать globals()[var_name]

Comment: Сейчас в вопрос допишу, что у меня получилось...

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar, так вы имя переменной (ключ словаря) выводите. чтобы вывести значение пишите  `print(globals()[var_name])`